# Writing bit stream to standard output in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

This should be simple to do but I have not been able to figure it out as of yet.  I am supposed to pipe a continuous stream of bits into a program, so that the stream of bits looks like `10010100010000001111101001`.  The issue I am having is the conversion: the program I have returns either a 0 or a 1 **integer** for each iteration of the loop, and I want it to write to standard output the bit 0 or the bit 1 dependent on if the program returns the integer 0 or 1.

How can I go about doing this?  Right now I am using

```
while True:
    val = f(x)
    if(val % 2 == 0):
        sys.stdout.write("{0:b}".format(0))

    else:
        sys.stdout.write("{0:b}".format(1))
```

But his is not working, as it is not just returning the raw 0/1 bit that I am trying to get.  Can anyone say how I can convert a 0 or 1 integer into a raw bit, and then write just that bit to standard output, so that I can pipe the bitstream into the program as follows

```
python script.py | program
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to combine 8 bits to make on byte:

```
while True:
    val = sum(f(x) << i for i in range(8))
    sys.stdout.buffer.write(bytes([val]))
```

Comment: In your case, is the `f(x)` an integer?  I need to return the bit of 0 or 1 dependent on if the integer f(x) is odd or even

Comment: `f(x)` is the function you defined, so yes, it returns an integer

Comment: ok but then if I understand your code correctly this returns the byte representation of `f(x)`, not just the single bit.  How can I get it to return just the single bit?

Comment: You cannot output one bit at a time to stdout